Cache@2 Azure DevOps pipeline task fails
I'm trying to use the Cache@2 task to cache my nuget packages. Following the documentation, I've setup the following tasks:
variables:
  nugetPackages: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nuget/packages
  
stages:
  - stage: CI
    displayName: 'Continuous Integration'
    jobs:
      - job: 'CI'
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
            displayName: 'NuGet tool installer'

          - task: Cache@2
            inputs:
              key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**,!**/obj/**'
              restoreKeys: |
                nuget | "$(Agent.OS)"
                nuget
              path: $(nugetPackages)
            displayName: Cache NuGet packages

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'Restore Packages'
        inputs:
          command: 'restore'
          feedsToUse: 'select'
          vstsFeed: '<DevOpsArtifactFeedId>'
          projects: 'Solution.sln'

But in the Post-job task, it fails with:
tar: /home/vsts/work/1/.nuget/packages: Cannot open: No such file or directory
It seems that the nugetPackages path may be incorrect, but I'm not sure what it should be. Although looking at the nuget restore task, I can see log entries such as:
Installed System.Text.Json 7.0.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json to /home/vsts/.nuget/packages/system.text.json/7.0.0
Which doesn't have the /work/1/ paths. I tried using $(Agent.HomeDirectory) instead of $(Pipeline.Workspace) but that didn't work either.
If I hard code the nugetPackages variable to '/home/vsts/.nuget/packages' then it works - but this feels dirty and I'd rather use an appropriate DevOps variable in case the path name changes

If you set the Cache task path to $(NUGET_PACKAGES) as per the example in docs, does it help? AFAIK, this environment variable is also used internally by NuGet during restore. Unfortunately, this is completely unclear from the docs.

If that's the case, you can set the nuget path also for the restore task using restoreDirectory and it should work. Note also that the cache needs quite some fiddling to work well and works per branch so if you use PRs, it won't help much.

I agree with @Zdeněk Jelínek's comment to change the variable name nugetPackages to $(NUGET_PACKAGES).  Also you need to change the restore task from DotNetCoreCLI@2 to NuGetCommand@2.
According to the pipeline caching document, the NUGET_PACKAGES is an environment variable.

If you use PackageReferences to manage NuGet dependencies directly within your project file and have a packages.lock.json file, you can enable caching by setting the NUGET_PACKAGES environment variable to a path under $(UserProfile) and caching this directory.

When I tested the same yaml as yours in my pipeline, I can reproduce the same error in the Post-job task.

Then I changed to use the official document sample, the Post-job task works.
However, when I only change the variable name nugetPackages to $(NUGET_PACKAGES) in your yaml, the pipeline still doesn't work. The difference is the restore task. So, I changed the restore task to NuGetCommand@2 restore . This time it works.

The changed yaml:
variables:
  NUGET_PACKAGES: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nuget/packages
  
stages:
  - stage: CI
    displayName: 'Continuous Integration'
    jobs:
      - job: 'CI'
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
            displayName: 'NuGet tool installer'

          - task: Cache@2
            inputs:
              key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**,!**/obj/**'
              restoreKeys: |
                nuget | "$(Agent.OS)"
                nuget
              path: $(NUGET_PACKAGES)
            displayName: Cache NuGet packages
          - task: NuGetCommand@2
            displayName: 'NuGet restore'
            inputs:
              command: 'restore'
              restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
              feedsToUse: 'select'
              vstsFeed: 'feedID'



Thanks to both yourself and @Zdeněk Jelínek. What you say makes sense. Although I find it frustrating that this isn't clear in the documentation because 1) How am I to know it's an environment variable? I have other variables that are declared in camelCase in my real pipeline so I just changed it for conformity. 2) I understand that using dotnet restore is favourable for .net core projects (performance being one factor), so it seems I have to revert to the older/slower nuget cli for this to work? Both of these facts should be mentioned in the documentation I feel

Hi @DavidMasters, yes, the document seems not very clear. By the way, I also found an interest thing that after the pipeline works in my answer, I changed the yaml back to the yaml in the question with nugetPackages and DotNetCoreCLI@2, the pipeline also worked.  It feels like we just need to use $(NUGET_PACKAGES) and NuGetCommand@2 for the first time to make the pipeline succeed and something is logged in the system. Then we can use  nugetPackages and DotNetCoreCLI@2 instead of $(NUGET_PACKAGES) and NuGetCommand@2.
